# Turning an integer to its binary representation using C?

Tags: c, binary

I'm still a beginner in coding so I had this problem
I'm trying to convert an integer into its binary representation

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main () {
   int x;
   printf("input the number\n");
   scanf("%d",&x);

   while(x!=0) {
     if (x%2)
       printf("1");
     else
       printf("0");
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

So it outputs like this 12=0011 but 12=1100
What is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: Your code snippet does not compile.

Comment: its not full i know i just wanted to show you my question

Comment: This is an infinite loop.

Comment: I'll have to assume you have `x = x / 2;` in the loop if you really have '0011' as output. It's good you have edited the problem to a bare minimum, but please don't over do it!

Comment: yea i did,thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Program Logic for the operation is wrong , try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, c, k;

    printf("Enter an integer in decimal number system\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d in binary number system is:\n", n);

    for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        k = n >> c;

        if (k & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        }

        printf("\n");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is not always 4. `CHAR_BIT` is not always 8. Indentation is missing.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to use recursion.

```
void put_binary (unsigned int x)
{
    if (x <= 1) 
    {
        putchar('0' + x);
    }
    else
    {
        put_binary (x / 2u);
        putchar ('0' + x % 2u);
    }
}
```

A more efficient way use bitwise operators (it prints every digits).

```
#define GET_BIT(x, i) (((x) >> (i)) & 1)

void put_binary (unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int max = sizeof x * CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0u; i < max; i++)  
    {
        putchar ('0' + GET_BIT (x, max - i - 1u));
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no way i can flip the printed sentence?

Comment: output for value '0' is nothing with the recursion.

Comment: Is there any reason for restricting the variable x to be an `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool seeOne = false;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
{
  int bit = (x >> sizeof(int) - 1 - i) & 1;
  if (bit)
  { 
    print("1");
    seeOne = true;
  }
  else
  {
    if (seeOne)
      print("0");
  }
}
```