# Generate an integer binary representation using Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

How to create a function accepting any type of Int or Uint in swift
(and calculating number of bits needs regarding param type)

Answer (score 30):

`String` has constructors

```
init<T : _SignedIntegerType>(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)
init<T : _UnsignedIntegerType>(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)
```

which can be used here:

```
let num = 100
let str = String(num, radix: 2)
print(str)
// Output: 1100100
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little shorter version. It doesn't add extra leading zeroes though:

```
func bitRep<T: IntegerArithmeticType>(value: T) -> String {
    var n: IntMax = value.toIntMax()
    var rep = ""
    while(n > 0){
        rep += "\(n % 2)"
        n = n / 2;
    }
    return rep
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Little shorter your modest. 'IntegerArithmetic' was my missing link.

Comment: `IntegerArithmetic` is called `IntegerArithmeticType` in the current beta version, I have taken the liberty to edit your code to make it compile again. - But note that your function returns the string reversed, e.g. `bitRep(8) = "0001"` instead of `"1000"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let binStr:Int->String = {a in return String(a, radix: 2)}
binStr(7) // "111"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function using Generics in order to accept any type of Int or Uint without param conversion needs.

1- The function needs to constraint a value type conforming to "ToInt" protocol
in order to offer an unique method to convert self type to Int

2- The function calculates length bit needs regarding param type

3- The function insert space every 8 digits to offer legibility

```
protocol ToInt { func toInt() -> Int }

extension UInt: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension Int8: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt8: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension Int16: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt16: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension Int32: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt32: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension Int64: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt64: ToInt { func toInt() -> Int { return Int(self) } }

func bitRep<T:ToInt>(value: T) -> String {
    var size: Int
    switch value {
    case is Int8, is UInt8: size = 7
    case is Int16, is UInt16: size = 15
    case is Int32, is UInt32: size = 31
    case is Int64, is UInt64: size = 63
    default : size = 63
    }
    var n = value.toInt()
    var rep = ""
    for (var c = size; c >= 0; c--) {
       var k = n >> c
       if (k & 1) == 1 { rep += "1" } else { rep += "0" }
       if c%8 == 0 && c != 0 { rep += " " }
    }
    return rep
}
```

Some examples:

```
let b1: UInt8 = 0b00000000
bitRep(b1)

// > "00000000"

let c1: UInt16 = 0b00000000_10000101
bitRep(c1)

// > "00000000 10000101"

let e1: UInt64 = 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001
bitRep(e1)

// > "00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001"
```

and so on!

(algo inspired from this thread: [Turning an integer to its binary representation using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115646/turning-an-integer-to-its-binary-representation-using-c))

Comment: what is the reason of `toInt`? `Int(value)` will do the same thing but it still won't work for integer larger than `Int.max`

Comment: @BryanChen You can't call `Int(value)` on an unknown type, so you need some constraint to use.

Comment: @ahruss there is a common type to all integer types, you can use it. (it is called `Integer` or something I can't recall now)