# Binary value of a Character in pure Swift

Tags: swift, binary, character

I need to convert a character in its binary string.

Ex : C = 34 = "1000011"

My work in progress look like this. It's work only for "C" character :

```
import Foundation

func charToBin(c:Character) -> String {
    let binaire = 34
    return String(binaire, radix: 2)
}

let c:Character = "C"
let b = charToBin(c)
```

Comment: Do you mean getting its ASCII value and converting it to binary?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do ;-)

Comment: If you're stuck on the ASCII part, try looking here- http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835826/938227

Comment: And if it's the integer to binary part, you can look here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986319/generate-an-integer-binary-representation-using-swift

Comment: The trick is you need to convert the characters back into `String` to access its ASCII representation (`..unicodeScalars`), e.g. `let binaire = String(c).unicodeScalars.first?.value ?? 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help :

I solved my problem with this code :

```
func stringToBinaryString (myString:String) -> String {

    // Array of characters
    let characterArray = [Character](myString.characters)

    // Array of asccii value
    let asciiArray = characterArray.map({String($0).unicodeScalars.first!.value})

    // Array of binary value
    let binaryArray = asciiArray.map ({ String($0, radix: 2)})

    // Reduce in a String
    let r = binaryArray.reduce("",combine: {$0 + " " + $1})

    return r
}

// Sample use :
let r = stringToBinaryString("CC")
```